# Flutter and realtime table in Supabase

Tags: flutter, dart, mvvm, supabase

I am using Provider to listen to realtime changes in a Supabase table.

Using MVVM the view is initialised by listening to the realtime table "poll_options"

poll_screen.dart

```
@override
void initState() {
  asyncLoadData();
  super.initState();
}

Future<void> asyncLoadData() async {
await Provider.of<PollScreenViewModel>(context, listen: false)
        .subscribeToRealtimeVoteTable("poll_options");
}
```

The ViewModel has a function that subscribes to realtime changes:

poll_screen_viewmodel.dart

```
Future<void> subscribeToRealtimeVoteTable(String name) async {
    var client = _supabaseService.getClient();
    client.from(name).on(SupabaseEventTypes.all, (x) {
      if (_pollPresentation != null) {
        _pollPresentation = PollScreenPresentation(
          id: x.newRecord['id'],
          homeScreenImageUrl: x.newRecord['homeScreenImageUrl'],
        );
      }
      notifyListeners();
    }).subscribe();
  }
```

My question is: How do I remove the subscription when using Provider and MVVM when the view is disposed?

```
@override
void dispose() {
  // TODO: implement dispose
  super.dispose();
}
```

If I would have all the code in the same class I would just call:

```
client.removeSubscription(client);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could probably create a `dispose()` method in your `poll_screen_viewmodel.dart` and call it from your `dispose()` method within the widget?

Add this to your `poll_screen_viewmodel.dart`

```dart
void dispose() {
  client.removeSubscription(client);
}
```

Add this on `poll_screen.dart`

```dart
@override
void dispose() {
  Provider.of<PollScreenViewModel>(context, listen: false).dispose();
  super.dispose();
}
```